# How to print out a list used as a class attribute or instance attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been playing with this for a little while now and can't see to figure it out. I have a simple class and want to use a list as either a shared class attribute or even just a instance attribute. Obviously, at some point it would be nice to see what is in this list, but all I can get to return is the object info (`<__main__.Testclass instance at 0x7ff2a18c>`). I know that I need to override the `__repr__` or `__str__` methods, but I'm definitely not doing it correctly.

```
class TestClass():
   
   someList = []

   def __init__(self):
      self.someOtherList = []

   def addToList(self, data):
      self.someOtherList.append(data)
      TestClass.someList.append(data)

   def __repr__(self):
      #maybe a loop here? I've tried returning list comprehensions and everything. 
      pass

test = TestClass()
test.addToList(1)
test.addToList(2)
test.addToList(3)

print(test.someList)
print(test.someOtherList)
```

I just want to see either `[1,2,3]` or `1 2 3` (hopefully choose either one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `test.someList` and `test.someOtherList`, you can *already* see what is inside those lists...

If you want to see those lists when printing the `test` object, you can either implement `__str__` or `__repr__` and delegate the representation of the instance to one of those. (either `someList` or `someOtherList`)

```py
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.someOtherList)
```

Now whenever you print your `test` object, it shows the representation of `self.someOtherList`.

```py
class TestClass:
    someList = []

    def __init__(self):
        self.someOtherList = []

    def addToList(self, data):
        self.someOtherList.append(data)
        TestClass.someList.append(data)

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.someOtherList)


test = TestClass()
test.addToList(1)
test.addToList(2)
test.addToList(3)

print(test)
```

output

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: You're absolutely right. For whatever reason, the non-example problem I am actually working on still doesn't work correctly and appears to be setup identically except with different variable names. Regardless, I appreciate the help. Just out of curiosity, what side effects will overriding that method have? Will I have to manually include any other attributes I want to print out from now on?

Comment: @jcoop7777 You can safely override `__str__` and/or `__repr__` and use any of the attributes you want. While printing(or str() and repr() directly), Python will call them instead of the default representation which provided by `object` class. Let me know if you are talking about a special case.